# Converting a matrix array to matrix

Tags: r

I have a matrix in R. When I run `class(my.matrix)` it returns:

```
"matrix" "array"
```

Why do I get "array" when in fact I want a plain matrix? The same `class` output is returned when running `as.matrix(my.matrix))`.

Why is that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`class()` on a matrix will always return:

```
"matrix" "array"
```

Simple example:

```
> class(as.matrix(1))
[1] "matrix" "array"
```

This is because an array in R is a vector with multiple dimensions, and the matrix is a special type of array with exactly two dimensions, so every matrix is an array and this is what the `class` command on a matrix is telling us here, see http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Data-structures.html

Answer (score 2):

From the return value of the `class` function, it looks like this already is a matrix. It just happens that it is considered by R to be both a matrix *and* an array.